# CoreBluetooth connection with non iOS device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

After navigating through documentation and most BTLE and CB stackoverflow questions, I've reached a limit.

I am doing an iOS app that should communicate with BT 4.0 device. Ask for data, and recieve that particular data.
The documentation of the device says, for instance:
Request:
Data
Start   1   "d" Read Log command-code
comma   1   "," comma
Side    1   "l" or "r"  
comma   1   "," comma
Graph   1   "0", "1", or "2"    
comma   1   "," comma
End 1   ;   End of command character

Response:
Start   1   "d" Read Log Data command-code
comma   1   "," comma
Side    1   "l" or "r"  
comma   1   "," comma
Graph   1   "0", "1", or "2"    
comma   1   "," comma
End 1   ;   End of command character

The Android developer, that already did the same app, says "I am converting the string into byte massive, using the ASCII and send it to the BT adapter".
Well, sounds good. But how does it work when we have to work with CoreBluetooth?

As for now I established a connection between 2 devices, iPad and iPhone, well I understood basically how it works, but still have no idea how  and where to send these byte strings.

Any hints, ideas, anyone experienced something like this?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[yourConnectedPeripheral writeValue:[yourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forCharacteristic:theCharacteristicToWrite type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

To write, you'll have to use NSData, that's why there is the `dataUsingEncoding` (note that you can change the encoding if it's not the same as the Android app one), and with `CBCharacteristicWithResponse` you'll get to know it it was correctly written in the delegate method `peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:`

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will definitely try it. If it works,I accept your answer :)